# How to divide one input into 2 when doing responsive

Tags: input, responsive

[image: desktop]

[image: mobile phone]

I need my search form (1) to transform into this one (2) when screen-width is smaller than 768px. I don't have a single idea where to start and how can i do that. Maybe someone can give me any hints?

tried flexbox, grid but still can't do anything about the 2 row, where input divides into two

Comment: You can try media queries. Basically, you can set it in media queries when the screen is smaller than 768px, then change the css for a class/id.

Comment: In your case, the design is totally different (eg, check-in date label is present only on mobile), so you can probably just create this div to show upon reaching 768 and below while hiding the desktop version using media queries.